# Font size increase on hover problems?

Tags: html, css, text, hover

The problem I'm getting is that when I mouse over the home the font size increases but the text moves down. I tried transform translate, I tried to do position relative then top 25px or whatever but didn't work.

here's the hover part:

```
home:hover{   
    font-size: 25px;

}
```

Here's the HTML part:

```
<nav> |<home> Home </home>| <photos> Photos </photos> | <contact> Contact </contact> | </nav>
```

Here's the CSS for the text of the nav:

```
nav{   
    color: #ddfeff;
    font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    word-spacing: 125px

}

home{
    color: #ddfeff;
    font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    word-spacing: 125px

}

photos{
    color: #ddfeff;
    font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    word-spacing: 125px

}

contact{   
    color: #ddfeff;
    font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    word-spacing: 125px

}
```

If you think you need any other bits of script let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: sounds like you're looking for the **line-height:** property.

Comment: @jbutler483 sorry I'm very new to HTML / CSS, what would I do with line height? Where would i put it?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Comment: @jlowcs I took a look at the before but I didn't really understand where I would put it and what value to use for it

Comment: Dude, there's even a "try it yourself" link on that page. If that's not enough for you to understand, there's not much I can do.

Comment: So I did:  
nav{   
    color: #ddfeff;
    font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    word-spacing: 125px
    line-height: 100%;
    
}                               but now it's all bunched up and it still moves up and down

Comment: Now just add a vertical-align like in my answer.

Comment: @jlowcs did a bit of fiddling and got it to work! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a vertical-align ?

```
nav > * {
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dchkdbvq/

Comment: Still seems to be moving up and down for me, it's not staying still

Comment: The text is not really moving. It's the height of the container that's changing, because the size of the text is changing. Use either "height" or "line-height" to set a fixed height.